# What difference between a WebSphere Message Broker and WebSphere MQ?

Tags: architecture, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

For me it is not clear what the difference is between a WebSphere Message Broker and the WebSphere MQ .

According to wikipedia the message broker translates and routes the message. Which would lead me to believe the WebSphere MQ is the queue, but it is not clear from all of the marketing information what the core task of the WebSphere MQ is. Wikipedia says MQ is composed of messages, queues, and queue managers.

Does that mean WebSphere Message Broker is a component of MQ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609705/difference-between-queue-manager-and-message-broker

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere Message Broker is not a component of WebSphere MQ Series (moreover, starting from v10 of Message Broker you don't need to have WebSphere MQ installed at all on your system in order to run message broker).

Think about WebSphere MQ as of a transport layer - you can send a message and receive it on another end (and all other particularities like persistence, fail-over, JMS, etc.)

Think about WebSphere Message Broker as of a set of transformations you can apply on your message (which **may** be transported via WebSphere MQ layer)

Answer (score 1):

If an analogy helps, MQ is like an HTTP client and HTTP server, whereas MB/IIB is more of a gateway (proxy).  Usually they emphasize **disparate systems** and **transformations** in the MB/IIB context.

Answer (score 0):

WebSpher MQ is an implementation of JSM plus a bit more, Message Broker or IIB as its called now is an ESB, It enables communication between separate system by transforming message from one definition to another.

MQ is one of the many transport channels that WMB can use to send and receive messages.